# How do I handle a value used in a query that has special characters?

Tags: rally

I'm trying to query by iteration but our iteration names have special characters (e.g. "Sprint - 01 (Mar 26, 2012 to Apr 02, 2012)").

> Cannot parse object reference from "Sprint - 01 (Mar 26, 2012 to Apr 02, 2012)""

If I add brackets around it all (e.g. '(Iteration = ' + '\"Sprint - 01 (Mar 26, 2012 to Apr 02, 2012)\")'

> Could not parse: Unknown operator ")"

How do I properly handle a value with these characters?

```
function itemQuery() {
  var queryObject = {
key: 'tasks',
type: 'task',
query: rally.sdk.util.Query.and(['State = "Completed"', 'TaskType = "Development"', 'Iteration = ' + '\"Sprint - 01 (Mar 26, 2012 to Apr 02, 2012)\"']),
fetch: 'FormattedID,Name,Owner,Estimate,Actuals'};

  rallyDataSource.findAll(queryObject, populateTable);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't the special characters but rather the query itself. When using the `=` operator for objects like iterations, it is expecting a ref, such as `/iteration/1234.js`.

Instead, you can query via the iteration's name with:

```
...
query: rally.sdk.util.Query.and([
    'State = "Completed"', 
    'TaskType = "Development"', 
    'Iteration.Name = ' + '\"Sprint - 01 (Mar 26, 2012 to Apr 02, 2012)\"'
])
...
```

The difference is the addition of ".Name" after iteration. Since the name is in quotations, the special characters can already make it into the web services without issue.

Comment: I've noticed that if I have "+" inside the iteration.Name the query doesnt get processed correctly. e.g., iteration name is "My-iteration1.0+". Did anyone else also observe this issue?

Comment: This worked for me when looking for tags. I used (Tags.name contains "something") and got what I wanted. Thanks!