# "Cannot parse object reference from", Rally

Tags: excel, rally

I'm trying to run a query on Rally using an Excel plugin based on iteration. I have established that the plug-in works by running a query for blocked stories. However, I get the following error when attempting to query by iteration:

Query failed due to errors:
Cannot parse object reference from "iterationname"

Matt Greer answered [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879339/how-do-i-handle-a-value-used-in-a-query-that-has-special-characters) in March, but I can't figure out how to translate this answer into making my query run. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the query you are trying to use?

Comment: it's not in script form - there's a GUI with pulldown menus, etc. to create the query and StackOverflow won't let me post the screenshot because I'm a new user. LMK how to get that to you and I will.

Comment: Perhaps just post the actual text of the query phrase? I.E. (Iteration.Name = "My Iteration") that's the most important part.

Comment: I don't have access to that. Like I said, it's a GUI interface with drop-down menus to build the query. The only free-form part is the name of the iteration (Forbearance) which I copy-pasted from the field in the Rally application. So it should work.

Comment: (Iteration.Name = "Forbearance")

Comment: That syntax should work. The error message: Cannot parse object reference from "iterationname" from your question suggests perhaps the  "." is missing between Iteration.Name? Otherwise maybe use a free service like http://tinygrab.com/ or Jing to share your screen shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query chooser in the Excel add-in is fairly primitive and really only works for fields that aren't objects themselves (ScheduleState, PlanEstimate, etc.)

Since you are querying a sub-object you can just type in the query manually in the textfield and save it.

(Iteration.Name = "Foo")

Comment: BTW, what I was doing wrong was just copy/pasting the iteration name from Rally into the search field in Excel. Because the plugin uses a GUI, it looks like to search by iteration, you simply choose "iteration" from the drop down menu and enter the iteration name into the text box. This will not work. You need to manually type Iteration.Name = "Foo" into the Filter field.

Comment: Wow, I had the exact same problem, I was trying to filter on a Release, and I ended up needing to change Release to Release.Name, and hey presto! It worked! Thanks!